# Java EDI X12 Parser

Tags: java, parsing, edi, x12

Is there any Good EDI parser API in Java? I know this is already [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077963/is-there-any-good-x12-parser-in-java), and I have gone through it.

I have an ANSI X12 EDI file.  It is an 846 Inventory Inquiry document:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *01*038211983      *ZZ*JWN-DSD        *130715*1540*U*00401*000015956*0*P*}
GS*IB*038211983*JWN-DSD*20130715*1540*15956*X*004010VICS
ST*846*159560001
BIA*00*MM*9480*20130715
REF*IA*103799
LIN**UP*887873083091
QTY*33*12*EA
LIN**UP*887873083107
QTY*33*13*EA
LIN**UP*887873083114
QTY*33*10*EA
LIN**UP*887873083121
QTY*33*6*EA
LIN**UP*887873083138
QTY*33*0*EA
SCH*0*EA***018*20391231

// Many lines this

LIN**UP*886732476371
QTY*33*0*EA
SCH*0*EA***018*20391231
LIN**UP*886732476388
QTY*33*0*EA
SCH*0*EA***018*20391231
SE*3283*159560001
GE*1*15956
IEA*1*000015956
```

From the link I mentioned above, I added [edireader](http://edireader.sourceforge.net/) jar to my Java program. When I given the above file, the output **XML** was like this

```
<ediroot xmlns="http://www.berryworkssoftware.com/2008/edireader">
<interchange Standard="ANSI X.12" Date="130715" Time="1540" StandardsId="U" Version="00401" Control="000015956">
<sender>
<address Id="038211983 " Qual="01"/>
</sender>
<receiver>
<address Id="JWN-DSD " Qual="ZZ"/>
</receiver>
<group GroupType="IB" ApplSender="038211983" ApplReceiver="JWN-DSD" Date="20130715" Time="1540" Control="15956" StandardCode="X" StandardVersion="004010VICS">
<transaction DocType="846" Control="159560001">
<segment Id="BIA">
<element Id="BIA01">00</element>
<element Id="BIA02">MM</element>
<element Id="BIA03">9480</element>
<element Id="BIA04">20130715</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="REF">
<element Id="REF01">IA</element>
<element Id="REF02">103799</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="LIN">
<element Id="LIN02">UP</element>
<element Id="LIN03">887873083091</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="QTY">
<element Id="QTY01">33</element>
<element Id="QTY02">12</element>
<element Id="QTY03">EA</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="LIN">
<element Id="LIN02">UP</element>
<element Id="LIN03">887873083107</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="QTY">
<element Id="QTY01">33</element>
<element Id="QTY02">13</element>
<element Id="QTY03">EA</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="LIN">
<element Id="LIN02">UP</element>
<element Id="LIN03">887873083114</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="QTY">
<element Id="QTY01">33</element>
<element Id="QTY02">10</element>
<element Id="QTY03">EA</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="LIN">
<element Id="LIN02">UP</element>
<element Id="LIN03">887873083121</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="QTY">
<element Id="QTY01">33</element>
<element Id="QTY02">6</element>
<element Id="QTY03">EA</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="LIN">
<element Id="LIN02">UP</element>
<element Id="LIN03">887873083138</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="QTY">
<element Id="QTY01">33</element>
<element Id="QTY02">0</element>
<element Id="QTY03">EA</element>
</segment>
<segment Id="SCH">
<element Id="SCH01">0</element>
<element Id="SCH02">EA</element>
<element Id="SCH05">018</element>
<element Id="SCH06">20391231</element>

//Many lines

</segment>
</transaction>
</group>
</interchange>
</ediroot>
```

Don't know its correct or not. But the problem is **edireader** is not in maven. So we have to manually add. So in future if new version of EDI comes, it will not work with same **edireader**.

[Smooks](http://www.smooks.org/) is not able to read X12 I think. I don't find it useful. And it needs to have some configuration file for reading file. So for each type for x12 file I will need different configuration

So is there any good **`Java EDI X12 Parser API`**?

Comment: Your sample file is X12.  It is an Inventory Inquiry/Advice document.  Smooks' problem is that in the sample, it is neither X12 or EDIFACT, but a proprietary flat file. I don't expect anyone to make heads / tails of that.  Why don't you look into something like MapForce (http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html)?  Everyone here always wants to reinvent the wheel and doesn't bring anything new to the paradigm.  EDI to XML translation has been beaten to death.

Comment: How can I use it? Where can I download the API for that? I find only the trial version

Comment: MapForce is commercial software.  You generate a map using their mapping utility, and it spits out Java code to embed in your application.  I think you are using the term API incorrectly and just need to write your own text parser.  This, of course, has its own set of problems - 997 generation, scalability, handling different delimiter sets.  Which is why all of these standalone EDI translators exist.  Yet people are forced to reinvent thirty year old wheels.

Comment: So what if I have different edi files of same `inventory` type? Will the auto generated Java code be able to read all those files? or will it read only the File that we uploaded first time?

Comment: 846 documents could (and probably will) vary be trading partner.  You could certainly make a generic map in the mapping tool to handle conditions based on partner, or you could create a map per partner to handle each specific document. In any EDI environment, that's a choice we usually have to make.  There are trade-offs.  To build a generic map to handle all partner requirements increases complexity of the map.  To have a map per partner will increase your codebase.

Comment: Also - this is why i recommend using commercial mapping/integration software that solves the problem of determining which partner sent data and what map to use and whether or not to generate a FA.  Look at (http://liaison.com/products/transform/delta) to compare what your research with MapForce shows you.

Comment: For Java, you may have some luck with the BOTS EDI system: https://github.com/bots-edi Main repo is here: https://github.com/bots-edi/bots