# Spring Integration for EDI

Tags: spring-integration

Our integration depends on spring integration, and some of our customers will send us EDI messages (EDIFact or AX12), would like to know if Spring integration will provide standard EDI transformers for us to use?

We need 2 kinds of transformers for our integration

1. EDI  to XML
2. XML to EDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:, [Is there any good X12 parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077963/is-there-any-good-x12-parser-in-java). Looks like most solutions for passing EDI are commercial. So, no, we are not going to provide out-of-the-box transformers in Spring Integration since we can’t rely on the non-Open Source library. But you go the route where you choose a library and use it from custom transformers in Spring Integration. Probably simple POJO method invocation would be enough for you.